# How to use both Custom and Detailed Error Modes under IIS7, IIS7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic, web-config, http-error

### The Condition

I have created my own web framework, which intercepts Error 404 and displays the appropriate content depending on the URL (it also sends the correct HTTP code 200 or 404 when the URL is valid or not). I have the entire framework under single **/Default.asp** (which includes several files, but that's not important here). It works perfect under IIS6, but I'm  unable to figure out how to handle debugging and development under IIS7.

### The Problem

The challenge is picking the correct Error Mode for the web.config file.
If I set **errorMode=Custom** then my code works and I can even see errors in my code while developing, but I can't debug other ASP files, because any error there, would be redirected to the **/default.asp** instead of showing it to me in the browser.

So, when I need to debug other ASP files, I would change the error mode from Custom to **errorMode=Detailed**

Then I can easily see the line number and the error description, but that means obviously that my framework would not be able to handle Errors 404 for non-existing URL's.

I have been doing this "dance" switching **web.config** every time I need to check something and it's getting very annoying. Here's my **web.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <!-- I'm changing Custom to Detailed here when I need to debug -->
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
     <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
     <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath=""
      path="/Default.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />

<!-- I have experimented with this, but unsuccessfully, so I comment it out
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" 
       path="/Default.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
-->

   </httpErrors>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## Question:

Is it possible to use both methods simultaneously?

A custom .ASP file to process 404 (and possibly other errors) but also leaving the 500 errors to be processed by the server and display the detailed error.

All I need to see is the line number and the error description.